# Проверка диапазона значений

Tags: inno-setup

Пытаюсь проверить, входит значение присвоенное некой переменной s в диапазон '0'..'9'. (Диапазон может быть другим). Можно написать как то так, чтобы не перечислять все значения? Я конечно догадываюсь, что можно проверить диапазон с помощью > < но может есть какой то другой путь?

```
procedure MyBeforeInstall();
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := '1';
  if s in '0'..'9' then //< ошибка Type mismatch
    MsgBox('in range', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  else
    MsgBox('out of range', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: @Saidolim. Кстати в Inno-Setup раздел [code] - служебный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже не актуально, но думаю можно решить путем написания функции на Delphi и экспортированием ее в InnoSetup.

InnoSetup:

```
function CheckRange(Value, MinValue, MaxValue : PChar): boolean;
external 'CheckRange@files:MyCommon.dll stdcall delayload';
```

Delphi:

```
function CheckRange(Value, MinValue, MaxValue : PChar): boolean; stdcall;
begin
   //проверка диапазона
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробую угадать:

```
if ord(s) in ord('0')..ord('9') then
```

Comment: Скорее всего конструкция if s in не поддерживается

Answer (score 0):

может так

```
procedure MyBeforeInstall();
var
  s: char;
begin
  s := '1';
  if s in '0'..'9' then //< ошибка Type mismatch
    MsgBox('in range', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  else
    MsgBox('out of range', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Попытка неплохая, но такое чувство что не поддерживается конструкция вида: if s in